# java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed in jhipster docker production for monolithic project

Tags: mysql, docker, angular6, jhipster, production

while running docker up i am getting  'java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed '.i am using jhipster monolithic project.and i have already tried 'allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true' solution.if am using that means again am getting one more error like 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'.please help me to solve this error.i stucked in same problem from 1 week.

here is my .yo-rc.json

```
{
 "generator-jhipster": {
"promptValues": {
  "packageName": "com.niche.ng",
  "nativeLanguage": "en"
},
"jhipsterVersion": "6.5.0",
"applicationType": "monolith",
"baseName": "Nichehands",
"packageName": "com.niche.ng",
"packageFolder": "com/niche/ng",
"serverPort": "8080",
"authenticationType": "session",
"cacheProvider": "ehcache",
"enableHibernateCache": false,
"websocket": false,
"databaseType": "sql",
"devDatabaseType": "mysql",
"prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
"searchEngine": false,
"messageBroker": false,
"serviceDiscoveryType": false,
"buildTool": "maven",
"enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
"rememberMeKey": "b9f603400b9bd1cf887c6efbba0e8e3822cf735d083441758e81667adef95db8af19462970cfece6048f0be25cc",
"embeddableLaunchScript": false,
"useSass": true,
"clientPackageManager": "npm",
"clientFramework": "angularX",
"clientTheme": "none",
"clientThemeVariant": "",
"testFrameworks": [],
"jhiPrefix": "jhi",
"entitySuffix": "",
"dtoSuffix": "DTO",
"otherModules": [],
"enableTranslation": true,
"nativeLanguage": "en",
"languages": [
  "en",
  "hi",
  "ta",
  "te"
],
"blueprints": []
}
}
```

Comment: I'm adding this as a comment because this error seems to be caused by a multitude of different reasons, each specific to the dev's project. My problem stemmed from a developer hardcoding the user creds into the DatabaseConfiguration.java class instead of using the ones passed in from application-dev.yml. I'm trying to upgrade a very old JHipster project and since I'm inheriting the code, I have to go exploring. Hope this helps!

Comment: hey @StackUser did you solve the problem i have the same problem, please share solution ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes:

- You want to use db connection as root user which is a bad idea because root have access to all database tables with all privileges. In some cases you want to add access for specific resources in db to your application.
- You are using a no password connection for DB

Possible solutions:

1. Add user for database (no root) for example in your db shell:

   `CREATE USER 'apppuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'topsecret';`

   `CREATE USER 'apppuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'topsecret';`

   `GRANT SELECT ON dbname.* to 'apppuser'@'localhost';`

   `GRANT INSERT ON dbname.* to 'apppuser'@'localhost';`

   `GRANT UPDATE ON dbname.* to 'apppuser'@'localhost';`

   `GRANT DELETE ON dbname.* to 'apppuser'@'localhost';`

   `GRANT SELECT ON dbname.* to 'apppuser'@'%';`

   `GRANT INSERT ON dbname.* to 'apppuser'@'%';`

   `GRANT UPDATE ON dbname.* to 'apppuser'@'%';`

   `GRANT DELETE ON dbname.* to 'apppuser'@'%';`

   Then change your docker-compose credentials
2. Related to first one. Create the .env file in docker-compose file path and add properties:

   `DBUSER='apppuser'`

   `DBPASSWORD='topsecret'`

   Then in your docker-compose file add this variables as a `${DBUSER} and ${DBPASSWORD}`.
3. Related to second point. If you have trouble with .env file and you are using linux system, add your environemnt propties in `/etc/environment` in the same way like in .env file. Remember that you can't use properties with '#' because it will be treated as a comment.

Please send your docker-compose file and production.yml file.